# Primality checker in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm brand new to prolog.
I've written the following code to test whether a number is prime.

```
notPrime(X):-
    integer(Y),
    Y>1,
    mod(X,Y) is 0.

prime(X):- \+ notPrime(X).
```

My thinking is: "If a number X ISN'T prime, then there exists an integer Y>1, such that X mod Y is 0."

The code doesn't work though, and I can't work out why.
Thanks :)

Comment: `integer(Y)`  where is the value for Y bound?

Comment: mod always fails with `no`, since Y is uninstantiated. mod only works with 2 instantiated Int variables

Comment: @nhahtdh The code never gets to the mod statement. It fails at `integer/1`.

Comment: Also, `prime(non_prime)` holds

Comment: *The code doesn't work though.* You haven't shown what kind of queries you want to run.